# SQL table structure - Reseller pricing

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to change the below structure to allow each account to check his sales and his profit, the scenario is when the a child account buy an item that's mean each parent account make his margin. maybe we should add a new table, I'm not sure

**Account** table:

```
 AccountId   ParentId   
 ----------- ----------- 
 5136        Null
 3126        5136        
 2123        3126
```

**Pricing** table: (this is the buying price for each account)

```
 AccountId   ItemId      Price
 ----------- ----------- -------------
 5136        211         0.14
 3126        211         0.175
 2123        211         0.19
```

**Sales** table:

```
  id   AccountId   ItemId       SellingDate
  --   ----------- -----------  ------------
   1   2123        211          2019-01-01 09:23:45
   2   2126        211          2019-01-01 10:07:21
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  Any attempt you have made would also help.

Comment: This doesn't read like you need a change to the structure of your database, but instead are after a `SELECT` statement, or perhaps a `VIEW` (Which I *suppose is* a structure change, but you're not changing the definition of the tables above).

Comment: For easy solution to add salesprice and buyingprice columns in sales table. So you can get all the details from sales table only.

Comment: there is multiple price for same record, example when the last child account buy an item that's mean each parent account make his margin
the item is owned by the main account, but the child account sell it, so there is hierarchy for rating this record, it should have parent prices as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add two new columns in your sales table 
 Quantity and SellingPrice.

```
  id   AccountId   ItemId       SellingDate             Quantity        SellingPrice
  --   ----------- -----------  ------------           ----------       ------------
   1   2123        211          2019-01-01 09:23:45         1               0.20
   2   2126        211          2019-01-01 10:07:21         1               0.30
```

Comment: the item is owned by the main account, but the child account sell it, so there is hierarchy for rating this record, it should have parent prices as well.

Comment: Keep purchase rate of all the child accounts in the price table.
And you can put an entry to sales table  as internal sales (parent account is selling product to child account)

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum level depth between a child and it's top parent is unknown.
Then not sure it requires a change to the tables.

For a given parent account you can use a recursive CTE to get it's children.
Then use that to get the sales and prices for the parent, including it's children.

```
WITH RCTE AS
(
   SELECT AccountId as BaseAccountId, 0 as Lvl, AccountId, ParentId
   FROM Account
   WHERE AccountId IN (5136, 3126, 2123)

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c.BaseAccountId, c.Lvl + 1, r.AccountId, r.ParentId
   FROM RCTE c
   JOIN Account r ON r.ParentId = c.AccountId
)
SELECT 
 c.BaseAccountId AS AccountId,
 COUNT(s.ItemId) AS TotalItems,
 SUM(p.Price) AS TotalPrice
FROM RCTE c
LEFT JOIN Sales s ON s.AccountId = c.AccountId
LEFT JOIN Pricing p ON p.ItemId = s.ItemId AND p.AccountId = c.BaseAccountId
GROUP BY c.BaseAccountId
ORDER BY c.BaseAccountId;
```

But then there better be an index on Account.ParentId

Comment: can we create a new table for pricing, "SalesPricing" that contain id from sales table, AccountId and price
example:
 saleId 1 accountId 2123 price 0.19
saleId 1 accountId 3126 price 0.175
saleId 1 .......

Comment: @DevL Something like a summary table for reporting that you fill once a month with Sales data from the previous month?  I suppose so. But then better add a partitioning on the selling year/month.  The current query could be tweaked by removing the GROUP BY and aggregations, then select the fields you need from it.  And put an `INSERT INTO` before the `SELECT`.

Comment: @DevL Maybe another idea is to create a new table with BaseAccountId, AccountID. Which you can fill using the recursive CTE trick.  Once you have that you can just JOIN the Sales and Pricing to that new table in the reporting query.

Comment: thank you @LukStorms you answers are very helpful! 
the sales table may has millions of records, in this case we will have a performance issue. 
I'm thinking to limit the number of child and add them as columns in the sales table. do you have other solution?

Comment: Things like recursive CTE's can be done via fixed left joins when you are certain that there are only like 2 levels between a top parent Account and a child.  But i guess that won't help much.  I suggest that the Sales table should be partitioned on the year&month of the selling date, or it's first day of the month. If you use such YYYYMM in a query that will help performance.  Adding the childs in the Sales table seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Well, if there are only 2 levels then instead of adding something to Sales, it might be better to add something like ParentAccount, HeadAccount foreign keys in the Accounts table.  Then you can query the accounts table based on 3 values . `WHERE @AccountId IN (AccountId, ParentAccount, HeadAccount)`

Comment: I forget to mention for you that the item price can be updated, so I have to place the Item price somewhere after selling it, I can't depend  on the join with pricing table because any price update can change the invoice values

Comment: But then besides adding columns like `Price2, Price3`, you'd have to also add columns like `AccountId2, AcountId3`.  To know which price to SUM for the given accountId. I suppose that would make querying the Sales table easier, because less joins needed.  Inserts & updates will become more complicated though.  Another method that's sometimes used is adding DATE columns to the reference data. A form of versioning.  For example `ActiveDate`, or `StartDate, EndDate`.  But then the query will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: Adding a StartDate & EndDate DATE type fields to the Pricing table is easiest to join with the date of the SellingDate.  `... LEFT JOIN Pricing p ON p.ItemId = s.ItemId AND p.AccountId = c.BaseAccountId AND CAST(s.SellingDate AS DATE) BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate`. But then you have to be super carefull that the ranges in the Pricing table don't overlap. Or it would join to multiple prices then. With an ActivDate then you could OUTER APPLY to a TOP 1, but that's less efficient.